# Numba / Numpy - Understanding Error Message

Tags: numpy, numba

I'm experimenting with Numba to try and speed up a union-find algorithm I'm working on.  Here's some example code. When I experiment with some sample data I cannot understand the type complaint that Numba appears to be raising.

```py
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

indices = np.arange(8806806, dtype=np.int64)
sizes = np.ones(8806806, dtype=np.int64)
connected_components = 8806806

@jit(npython=True)
def root(p: int) -> int:
    while p != indices[p]:
        indices[p] = indices[indices[p]]
        p = indices[p]
    return p

@jit(npython=True)
def connected( p: int, q: int) -> bool: 
    return root(p) == root(q)

@jit(npython=True)
def union( p: int, q: int) -> None:
    root1 = root(p)
    root2 = root(q)
    if root1 == root2:
        return

    if (sizes[root1] < sizes[root2]):
        indices[root1] = root2
        sizes[root2] += sizes[root1]
    else:
        indices[root2] = root1
        sizes[root1] += sizes[root2]

    connected_components -= 1
    
@jit(nopython=True)
def process_values(arr):
    for row in arr:
        typed_arr = row.astype('int64')
        for first, second in zip(arr, arr[1:]):
            union(first, second)
            
process_values(
       np.array(
           [np.array([8018361, 4645960]),
            np.array([1137555, 7763897]),
            np.array([7532943, 2248813]),
            np.array([5352737,   71466, 3590473, 5352738, 2712260])], dtype='object'))
```

I cannot understand this error:

```
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-62735e65f581> in <module>
     44             np.array([1137555, 7763897]),
     45             np.array([7532943, 2248813]),
---> 46             np.array([5352737,   71466, 3590473, 5352738, 2712260])], dtype='object'))            

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    399                 e.patch_message(msg)
    400 
--> 401             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    402         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    403             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py in error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    342                 raise e
    343             else:
--> 344                 reraise(type(e), e, None)
    345 
    346         argtypes = []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/utils.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
     78         value = tp()
     79     if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
---> 80         raise value.with_traceback(tb)
     81     raise value
     82 

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type array(pyobject, 1d, C)
[1] During: typing of argument at <ipython-input-45-62735e65f581> (36)

File "<ipython-input-45-62735e65f581>", line 36:
def process_values(arr):
    for row in arr:
    ^
```

Does this have anything to do with `process_values` taking an array of irregularly shaped arrays? Any pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that Numba does not accept arrays of dtype 'object'. You seem to be placing arrays inside arrays, you will have to use lists inside lists. Look for the `typed.List` class in Numba, https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#typed-list

Alternatively, you can use awkward arrays: https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0